# sql query: using insert and where query together

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

name     code       group

john      12
smith     15

how do I insert group for a specified row?

say for 'smith' I have to insert the group..
i tried to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO table (group)
VALUES ('usher') where code = 15
```

error:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

please help!!

thanks in anticipation!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     group = 'usher'
WHERE   code = 15
```

Comment: thanks bro!!
but ma real problem isnt solved yet...actually want d user to enter code and group....in d form,he'll enter d code and d group....on proceeding, i want the group to be updated....so i used parametrized query:
UPDATE table SET group='usher' WHERE code ='" + textBox2.Text + "' 
d program runs but no changes are reflected in the table...

i hope u understood d problem...
plz help

Comment: sry d query is wrong there...the actual query is:
"UPDATE table SET group(@n) WHERE code ='" + textBox2.Text + "'"
i doubt dis query as i m not sure of using d parameter 'n' bound with textbox2(d syntax)

however,even d first query doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure you commit the transaction after the query completes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer you want to perform an UPDATE not an INSERT.

UPDATE is used to change existing rows while INSERT will create new rows. Hence why WHERE can not be used with an INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Insert query doesn't support where keyword* Conditions apply because you can use where condition for sub-select statements.